# CodeIgniter dynamic URI routing possible?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri

My application is designed to provide a single profile page for each user, with the 3rd segment being the user's ID.

```
example.com/profile/page/1
```

Assuming user 1 is "Jon Jovi", using CI's routing I would like to generate this URI

```
example.com/jon_jovi
```

Is it possible to send this user's ID to `config/routes.php`, run a function to extract user 1's info from database and insert it like

```
$route['profile/page/$row->id'] = $row->first_name . '_' . $row->last_name;
```

Any thought or suggestions on how to do this are much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to the "client" url to be in format `base_url/[username]`, you will probrably need to grab the username some regex routing, like `$route['([a-zA-z_]+)'] = "profile/page/$1";`, and look on your database for that user.

Another solution would be appending the id to the url, like `base_url/[username]/[id]`. For this, the regex `$route['([a-zA-z_]+)/([0-9+])'] = "profile/page/$2";` would pass the id as the first parameter for the page function of Profile controller.

Check the Documentation for more details on dynamic routing: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: thanks @julio, but where would the database lookup be placed? would this go in routes.php calling a function/model elsewhere? if you have time for an example that would be great.

Comment: @torr using the first routing, if you access `base_url/foo`, it would call the `page` function from the `Profile` controller. The username (in this case, foo) would be passed as the first parameter for the function.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure this needs to be in your `config/routes.php` at all: why don't you just create a controller that takes the name and does the lookup?

EDIT: I take it back. This is actually kinda painful to do, particularly because you want it to live on the root of the domain (i.e. it would be easy to to do *example.com/p/{username}*, but *example.com/{username}* is messy).

Easiest way to do this is to use CodeIgniter 2.0+'s ability to override the 404 handler and the `_remap` function. First, do this in the *config/routes.php* file:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'notfound';
```

Then create the controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class NotFound extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function _remap($method)
  {
    if($this->uri->total_segments() == 1){
      // try it out
      $this->profile();
    }else{
      show_404($this->uri->uri_string());
    }
  }

  function profile()
  {
    echo "Showing profile for [" . $this->uri->segment(1) . "]";
  }
}
```

You have to implement a view for the 404 page as this overrides it, but any requests that don't map to an existing controller come in here and you can dispatch them however you want, including translating the name into a db ID.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks @femi - do you have an example for your suggestion? is it possible to name controller functions with a dynamic name in CI?

Comment: Very neat solution. I've ended up with _example.com/p/{id}_ a few times since I couldn't figure out how to drop the controller, doing this never crossed my mind. I'll be sure to remember this the next time.

Comment: this doesn't make sense... i think this is over-complicating what can be done simple. following @Julio's example, it's a better practice to use routes.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question to this a few weeks ago. I have copy-pasted the relevant part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129471/custom-url-in-codeigniter-using-htacess/6129676#6129676) below:

> You'll want to extend CI's router and
>   on an incoming request query the DB
>   for the list of company names. If the
>   URI segment matches a company name,
>   you'll want to serve it up using your
>   company/profile method. If it does
>   not, you will ignore it and let CI
>   handle it normally. Check out this
>   post on this topic for more
>   information: [forum link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/121486/).

In this case, just swap out "company" and "company/profile" for "username" and "profile/page" to make it relevant to your question.